# Upgrading debian squeeze to sid

Tags: debian, upgrade, lock

Atm I am trying to upgrade my debian squeeze to sid. I followed this tutorial:
www(.)digitalocean.com/community/articles/upgrading-debian-to-unstable

Everything seems to work well until Step 3. While upgrading it doesn't ask me questions. It seems to install everything.. it durates about 15 minutes.

My sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian(.)org/debian sid main

deb http://ftp.de.debian(.)org/debian squeeze main

deb http:/ftp.de.debian(.)org/debian sid main contrib non-free

# ofc without (.)
```

When I try to use dist-upgrade it says:

```
root@xyz:/home/myname# apt-get dist-upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT (removed):
  console-terminus defoma fuse-utils gcj-4.4-base gcj-4.4-jre gcj-4.4 jre-headless (...) xserver-xorg-video-nv
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
acl akonadi-backend-mysql ant ant-optional aptitude-common (...) xserver xorg-input-vmmouse xulrunner-17.0
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
  acpi acpi-support-base acpid adduser (...) xterm xz-utils zip zlib1g
979 aktualisiert, 555 neu installiert, 58 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
E: Konnte Sperre /var/cache/apt/archives/lock nicht bekommen - open (11: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
E: Das Verzeichnis /var/cache/apt/archives/ kann nicht gesperrt werden
```

(german -> english)

```
E: Couldn't get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: The ressource isn't available)

E: The directory /var/cache/apt/archives/ can't get locked
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have another package manager running simultaneously. Check if there are other instances of `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `synaptic`, `update-manager` or other package managers running and close them before starting the dist-upgrade.

It is possible that `update-manager`, the graphical update manager was launched automatically after `apt-get update` when new updates became available.

You can remove the lock file manually, but it is very much recommended to close the program holding the lock normally since interrupting an ongoing installation can cause system corruption. The following command will kill the program holding the lock and delete the lockfile, but it won't protect from any side effects caused by installation interruption.

```
su -c 'fuser -cuk /var/cache/apt/archives/lock; rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/lock'
```

Comment: I closed them all with pkill. But it's still the same error.

Comment: After I copied this into my terminal, my screen turned black and nothing happened. After restart I tried dist-upgrade, but it didn't really work. :
Need to get 0 B of archives or of 941 MB.
After this operation, 215 MB disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y

Comment: That message is normal during a dist-upgrade. Is there an error that was cut off from the paste to the comment field?

Comment: No, these are the only messages.

Comment: That is entirely normal. You need to confirm the dist-upgrade by typing 'y' or 'yes' and pressing Enter.

Comment: Yes I did it.. but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are there any errors in '/var/log/dpkg.log'?

Comment: Really big file.. But by searching with strg-f I can find these: http://pastebin.com/uehBbihn

Comment: Those are not errors but status messages pertaining to a package called 'libgpg-error0'. Any messages related to the most recent package management operations would be at the end of the file.

Comment: Oh.. I don't know if this helps but here are the recent ones. http://pastebin.com/Lb0jr09B

Comment: The logs seem too old according to the timestamps to be related to the dist-upgrade. Can't really say that I would have seen anything like what you describe before. Regarding your sources.list, it is usually a bad idea to mix packages from different releases, although I don't see how that would cause this. Maybe try rerunning `apt-get update` and try the dist-upgrade again. After confirmation, `apt-get` should start reading the package database, are you sure it actually hangs instead of just taking awhile?

Comment: Yes, the timestamps are really too old but there are also no new ones. I mixed the packages because the tutorial said this (?). And dist-upgrade only "works" (actually it doesn't really install anything, it just reads the changelogs) after a reboot. Otherwise I get this lock error. I think I will reinstall Debian. Is this sources.list correct? : http://pastebin.com/rk3R9xJQ

Comment: I believe you'd only need 'deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free' in sources.list. As far as I know there are no security repositories for Sid and I don't think 'Sid-updates' is a valid distribution specifier.

Comment: I installed it again, replaced everything in my 'sources.list' with 'deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free'. Then I performed these commands: apt-get update + apt-get dist-upgrade + reboot. But after reboot it's still 6.0.7 and repeating dist-upgrade doesn't work because of the lock error. Have I done anything wrong?